# django generic views:displaying records from database

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to django and python. i'm trying to display database records using `django` generic view but it is giving me an `error`

> ValueError at /updates/facilities_list/
>   The view updates.views.facilities_list didn't return an `HttpResponse` object.

It returned None instead.this is my code for views.py

```
def facilities_list(ListView):
    model = facilities
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined it as a method rather than a class

```
def facilities_list(ListView):
```

should be

```
class facilities_list(ListView):
```

Comment: Note: this will probably trigger changes needed to your urls (`as_view()`) and other settings needing defined such as `template_name`

Answer (score 0):

ListView is imported in Django Class based Views, and it can be done in given way:

```
class FacilitiesListView(ListView):
      model = Facilities
      queryset = Facilities.objects.all()
```

Use Django Class Based Views for imported any of Django Genenic class based Views.

Also define a template name or use default template name for it which is facilities_list.html in you facilities template folder.